# Loop though xml data. Only getting first result

Tags: php

I can't figure out how on earth why this is not looping through all the children. It's only showing the first child/result. Any help would be appreciated :)

**PHP for loop code:**

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('data.xml') or die('Failed to create an object');
  foreach($xml->children() as $xml_node) {          
    echo $xml_node->item->title . ", ";     
    echo $xml_node->item->description . ", ";     
}
```

**data.xml**

```
<rss xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>Reviews</title>
<description>5 Star Reviews</description>

<item>
<title>Review 1 on Google</title>
<description>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis</description>
<pubDate>Wed, 08 Jul 2020</pubDate>
</item>

<item>
<title>Review 2 on Google</title>
<description>Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</description>
<pubDate>Tue, 07 Jul 2020</pubDate>
</item>

<item>
<title>Review 3 on Google</title>
<description>Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, </description>
<pubDate>Fri, 26 Jun 2020</pubDate>
</item>

<item>
<title>Review 4 on Google</title>
<description>Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio </description>
<pubDate>Fri, 26 Jun 2020</pubDate>
</item>

</channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only getting the first child of the `rss` element, which is `channel`, the only child of `rss`. That tells it to only loop once. You need to specify that you want the children of `channel` which are multiple `item` elements.

Try the following instead:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('data.xml') or die('Failed to create an object');
  foreach($xml->channel->children() as $xml_node) {          
    echo $xml_node->title . ", ";     
    echo $xml_node->description . ", ";     
}
```

With that change, you can access the direct child elements of `item`: `title` and `description`.

Comment: @gimley - I have a question. I'm trying to take all the results from the foreach loop and place them into a simple HTML marquee that just scrolls from the right to the left. I have the HTML marquee outside the loop, so of course it's only displaying the last result of the loop. Could I put the loop results into an array maybe? and echo out the array into the marquee? Again the HTML marquee would have to be outside the foreach loop. I tried this and it's just scrolling the word Array. Example: https://codeshare.io/2E816X

Comment: Just concatenate the results of the loop into a string and echo that into the marquee. Or if you have the array already, just use a `join` to concatenate the contents.

Comment: @gimley - thanks for the feedback. I really appreciate your help. I've done what you mentioned and I think I'm doing it correctly but it's only displaying the last result (Review 4 on Google). It's not showing all the results together at once. Here is my code: http://codeshare.io/ar0jWv

Comment: Nevermind! I used `.=` so the final was `$xml_ticker .= join('', $arr);` and it worked. Before I was overriding the previous value, by using .= it allowed me to add it to the existing string.